# jquery curtain.js and fancybox-2 keyboard conflict

Tags: jquery, keyboard, conflict, fancybox-2

The jquery script is the following:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.fancybox').fancybox();

    $('.curtains').curtain({
        scrollSpeed: 300,
        controls: '.menu',
    })
})
```

jquery v1.7.1 is used and the plugins shown below.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="includes/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.js?v=2.1.4"></script>
<script src="includes/fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.js?v=1.0.5"></script>
<script src="includes/fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.js?v=1.0.7"></script>
<script src="includes/fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-media.js?v=1.0.5"></script>
<script src="js/curtain.js"></script>
<script src="js/myscript.js"></script>
```

Actually everything works perfect **BUT**,
when using the up, down, left, right keys to navigate the fancybox gallery (works fine),
curtain.js works at the same time in the background changing the various pages/curtains.
Is there any way to "disable" curtain.js when navigating the fancybox image gallery?

Answer (score 0):

According to [curtain's documentation](https://github.com/Victa/curtain.js/blob/development/v2.0/readme.md), you can use `enableKeys` for that purpose so you could re-init your curtain's script within the fancybox callbacks .... try this (untested) :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.curtains').curtain({
        scrollSpeed: 300,
        controls: '.menu'
    });
    $('.fancybox').fancybox({
        beforeShow: function () {
            $('.curtains').curtain({
                enableKeys: false // no keys while fancybox is open
            });
        },
        afterClose: function () {
            $('.curtains').curtain({
                scrollSpeed: 300,
                controls: '.menu',
                enableKeys: true // re-enable keys after fancybox is closed
            });
        }
    }); // fancybox
}) // ready
```